# Distribution of a project with external dll libraries

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have developed a program in C# with Visual Studio and now I need to distribute it.
For this I use Visual Studio Installer. My problem is with the dll libraries that the project detects as dependencies. With VSI I can install them in the folder I want, but the executable file needs to be in the same directory.
How can I group them in a folder so that my executable knows where to read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the "visual studio installer" seems to be the visual studio setup project.

First of all, you need to make your project supports the assemblies with "Copy Local = false": [Referencing dlls without copying them C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829393/referencing-dlls-without-copying-them-c-sharp)

Then you can create folders into Application Folder to distribute your assemblies.
[image]